# Validation a field in jQueryMobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile last version and jQuery.

I need validate a field, that would accept users's input.

In case the input is NOT A NUMBER I would like have a Error Validation message close to that field.

I would like to know how to make it in jQuery Mobile.

Also I would like to know if it is possible to force the User to add only Numeric value for a field.

Comment: Yes it is possible, but first show me what you have tried?

Comment: I'm not able to make it actually, if you are able to provide me a sample of code would be great. Let me know thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation`

In case you need custom validation take a look at `addMethod( name, method, message )` from this plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same `jquery.validate.js` plugin in jquery mobile. Other wise, you can add a class say `formField` to all the form fields that requires validation and on submit, get the elements containing field and do custom validation. If you are using the hash for each page, I would write some thing like:

```
<form class='myFormElem display-none'>
  <div class="errorField"
  <input type="text" data-regexp="^\+?[0-9]{10,15}$" class="formField">
  <input type="submit" class="submitForm">
</form
```

Sample code snippet:

```
$(location.hash + ' .submitForm').off('click');
$(location.hash + ' .submitForm').on('click', function (e) {
    $(location.hash + ' .formField').each(function () {
        var elem = $(this), p, regexp;
        try {
            //validate fields
            p = elem.data('regexp');
            if (p !== "" && p !== null && typeof p !== "undefined") {
                regexp = new RegExp(p, ["g"]);
                if (!val.match(regexp)) {
                    throw "Error..(your error message here)";
                }
             }
        } catch (ex) {
            $(errField).removeClass('display-none').addClass('display-block');
            $(errField).html(ex);
        }
    }
});
```